# Dynamic double validation Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a text input field where the user can only input a double.
I have successfully used jquery to implement this, but not having much experience with regular expressions I am not sure if the regex that I am using (which uses multiple ORs) is a good way of doing it. I spend a lot of time trying to get a simple regex, but I was unsuccesful. This is what I finally used.

Here is the function I am using:

```
$('#foo').keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    if(/(^\.+$)|(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.$)|(^\.\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)/.test(str)){
        $('#foosays').text(str);
    }else{
        $("#foo")[0].value="";
    }
});
```

Here is the demo of my function: http://jsfiddle.net/Esfsy/

Any suggestions to improve the regex or anything else are welcome.

Comment: In JavaScript all numbers are doubles... You may want convert string to number and use `isNaN` with `toFixed` instead of regex.

Comment: Just curious why was this question flagged for a 'close'?

Comment: Take a look at this page for relevant regexs: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Esfsy/3/

```
$('#foo').keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    if(/^-?(\d*\.)?\d*$/.test(str)){
        $('#foosays').text(str);
    }else{
        $("#foo")[0].value="";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I spend a lot of time trying to get the regex this way! I guess I have more reading to do.

Comment: @dandavis Thats true, I edited my answer to account for negatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo').keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    if( +str || str==='0'){ // validates as a number
        $('#foosays').text(str);
    }else{
        $("#foo")[0].value="";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple way! can you tell me what does the +str do?

Comment: +turns it into a number. you can also use 1*s, or Number(s) for better readability.